# How do I get a time stamp with ASP Classic from code?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am using:

```
<%= time %>
```

It's returning:

**5:12:19**

And it's 8:12:19 p.m. where I am

How can I make it print the local time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% myDateTime = DateAdd("h", 3, Time) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the LocaleId (Session.LCID or SetLocale(lcid)) for your own timezone before calling time. See more about [SetLocale and LocaleIDs on this page](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_setlocale.asp)